# My program works in the Python auto-grader of my online course but not on Linux?

Tags: python, linux

I'm working on assignment 7.1 on the Python for Everybody specialisation from coursera. The assignment is the following:

*"Write a program that prompts for a file name, then opens that file and reads through the file, and print the contents of the file in upper case. Use the file words.txt to produce the output below.
You can download the sample data at [http://www.py4e.com/code3/words.txt"](http://www.py4e.com/code3/words.txt%22)*

When writing my code in atom and running it in the Linux terminal, I found that it did not work (bearing in mind I made sure to save the file *words.txt* that was given to us in the same folder that I'm in when I usually start python). But when I ran this code in the web-based python autograder   that is used for this course I found that the code worked fine. Here it is:

```
# Use words.txt as the file name
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fhand = open(fname)
inp = fhand.read(fname)
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    new_inp = line.upper()
    print(new_inp)
```

When running this in the Linux terminal the syntax error I receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chapter7.1.py", line 2, in <module>
    fname = input("Enter file name: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'words' is not defined
```

Is this not working because I have misplaced the file(words.txt) even though I thought I stored it in the correct folder?  OR is this not working because of something else? In the past I have also had minor issues where code that runs in the python autograder online does not run in linux without a traceback. I have a chromebook if that's relevant at all and the software I downloaded to run python in linux is minoconda.

Comment: `fhand.read(fname)` -> just remove this statement. with `fname`, it should throw error (byte number is expected, not a string), and even without `fname` it will move pointer to the end of the file, which will screw the following loop

Comment: @Marat Read the error message again. That's not the problem OP's currently experiencing.

Comment: @wjandrea it might not be enough to fix the problem, but this statement definitely should be removed for the reasons I explained

Answer (score 1):

You're running it with Python 2. Run it with Python 3 instead.

To explain, in Python 2, `input()` **evaluates** the string it receives from the user, so when you give it `words.txt`, it parses `words` as a variable name, and `txt` as an attribute, but the variable `words` doesn't exist, hence the error. In Python 3, `input()` doesn't evaluate anything. For more details, start with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15129556/4518341).

Also note that you're receiving a `NameError`, not a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But even when I manually evaluate the user's input in my code I receive the same traceback.

Comment: @Shehzadi "Manually evaluate"? No, I'm saying that's the *opposite* of what you should do. Did you switch from Python 2 to 3?

Comment: Sorry i’m still a bit confused as to what you mean, Miniconda3 which is what I have installed on my computer, runs python 3 in Linux.

Comment: @Shehzadi Try replacing `input` with `raw_input` and see if it works.

Comment: @Shehzadi No need to apologize. I'm saying, in Python 3, `input()` should return **a string**, and there's no way that that error could occur, so I'm sure that you're running your code in Python 2, not Python 3. Maybe you haven't activated the conda environment or something. There is another alternative - that some part of your Python 3 config is overriding `input()` as `eval(input())` - but that seems ridiculous.

Comment: @Shehzadi To check what version and interpreter you're using, put this in a script: `import sys; print(sys.version); print(sys.executable)`

Comment: I can now see that linux is actually running python 2.7.16. So yes when changing input () to raw_input() the code actually does work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

The file name MUST be words.txt, without a capital w. If you type Words.txt, you will get the error mentioned.

Comment: This is nonsense. A NameError refers to Python variables not existing, not to filenames not existing; if the filename were wrong it would be a completely different error message. wjandrea's diagnosis is correct: the OP is using Python 2, wherein `input()`'s content is implicitly evaluated as code rather than returned as a string; hence, the filename is being treated as a variable name, thus the error. If the OP just changes it to `Words.txt`, they'll get a NameError about `Words` instead of `words`, but it'll still be an error.